# Dynamic function creation using globals() in python

Tags: python, pytest, global

I am trying to call a dynamic method created using `exec()`, after calling `globals()` it is considering `params` as fixture and returning error as fixture 'Template_SI' not found.

Can someone help on how to pass dynamic parameters using `globals()function_name(params)`?

```
import pytest 
import input_csv

datalist = input_csv.csvdata()


def display():
    return 10 + 5


for data in datalist:
    functionname = data['TCID']
    parameters = [data['Template_name'], data['File_Type']]
    body = 'print(display())'


    def createfunc(name, *params, code):
        exec('''
@pytest.mark.regression
def {}({}):
    {}'''.format(name, ', '.join(params), code), globals(), globals())


    createfunc(functionname, data['Template_name'], data['File_Type'], code=body)
    templateName = data['Template_name']
    fileType = data['File_Type']
    globals()[functionname](templateName, fileType)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to automate the generation of lots of different tests based on different input data.  If that's the case, using `exec` is probably not the best way to go.

pytest provides parameterized tests: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html

which accomplish test generation by hiding all the details inside [Metafunc.parameterize()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.python.Metafunc.parametrize).

If you really want to generate the tests yourself, consider adapting Metafunc to your own purposes.  Or, alternatively, checking the unittest framework.

Comment: can we add pytest.mark.regression as a marker while using metafunc.paramterize()